# setSupportActionBar cannot be applied to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

On this new project, when setting a toolbar into the main activity java file, it gets the error on

> "setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)" saying "getSupportActionBar() in
>   AppCompatActivity cannot be applyed to
>   (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)"

On similar questions, the answers was just to change from "import android.widget.Toolbar" to "import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar" which is already set.
The main activity xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
        >
    </include>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The toolbar I'm trying to insert is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And the main java file:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar =  findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("WhatsApp");
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? A compatibility set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a typo, and you're calling `getSupportActionBar()` (with a `g`) instead of `setSupportActionBar()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setSupportActionBar()` to configure toolbar in the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar =  findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("WhatsApp");
    }
}
```