# Application crashes when it goes from one activity to other

Tags: android

I am making UI in android studio.And problem occurs when my app switches between activities. Actually i put timer to switch from one activity to other of 3 second .When 3 second of time complete ,my app crashes insted of going into navigationdrawer activity(which is part of project).
And it shows the error in logcat
(navigationdrawer.java.18)
which becomes  setSupportActionBar(toolbar); error in java file

[setSupportActionBar cannot be applied to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962841/setsupportactionbar-cannot-be-applied-to-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar)
I have tried to find solution on different sites but could not find any solution.

`Navigationdrawer.java`

```
package com.example.zeeshan.myapplication;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    public class Navigationdrawer extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigationdrawer);
        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

`Navigationdrawer.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Navigationdrawer"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`Home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <TextView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="190dp"
   android:text="Welcome to Wheat yield Estimation App..."
   android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:textSize="35dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
   android:textStyle="italic"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Home.java

```
package com.example.zeeshan.myapplication;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import java.util.Timer;
 import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Timer timer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      timer=new Timer();
      timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,navigationdrawer.class);
            startActivity(intent);

          }
      },3000);
        }

}
```

style.xml

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>


</style>
</resources>
```

I was expecting that app will switch between activities but it does not and crashes ..

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: It's good if you can post the stacktrace. Otherwise, make sure you have activity/app theme doesn't have a actionbar already supplied to it (Note that the app/activity theme must end in with NoActionBar in your styles.xml)

Comment: please add  also your styles.xml

Comment: i just added style.xml

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity timer you have the following code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login.class);
```

You are going to this activity (Login) instead of the navigationdrawer activity you actually want to go to. Change the above code to:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Navigationdrawer.class);
```

Unless ofcourse if you have a Login activity and from that activity you end up in the NavigationDrawer activity, in which case please include the code and xml of that activity as well.

Comment: If i want to go from home activity to nevigationdrawer activity ,above error come. I just edit my code

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely just missing the below from your `AndroidManifest:`

```
<activity
android:name=".Navigationdrawer"
android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapplication">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
        android:name=".Navigationdrawer"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       />
```

Comment: I did add but still my app crashes when it goes to 2nd activity which is navigatondrawer